# Android How to detect application awake from background

Tags: android, background-process, onresume, onpause

May i know how to detect when apps is awake from the background??

the flow is:

1) The application is open

2) User tap home button to go out and using other apps(without exit)

3) User tap recent apps button and choose back current application

4) prompt a message to ask user insert pin number

I had tried using onPause/onUserLeaveHint and onResume, **but it won't work**

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sleep=true;
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(sleep) {
        if (!passcode) //no pin is set
        {
        }
        else if (passcode) //a pin is set
{ 
            Intent check_passcode = new Intent(this, CheckPasscode.class);
            check_passcode.putExtra("passcode_value", passcode_value);
            startActivity(check_passcode);
        }
        sleep = false;
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

the intent is prompt out every time i go to a new **Activity by intent**.

***I have many other activity call by intent.**

Comment: `"I had tried using onPause/onUserLeaveHint and onResume, but it won't work"` **onPause** doesn't work? how come?